# JQuery problem with HTML entities

Tags: jquery

I use this code to receive data from an php file

```
$.ajax({
                url: "includes/cpf.inc.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{p_request:"1bdd249a5d673a721be31d7444af81af1af4c5b6",
                        p_userid:"<?php echo $dbu_userid; ?>",
                        p_curpass:$("#txtcurpass").val(),
                        p_newpass:$("#txtnewpass").val(),
                        p_cnewpass:$("#txtcnewpass").val()
                },
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){
                    $("#chPassLoad").css("visibility","hidden");
                    wilPrompt("#chpasStat",msg.substr(0,1),msg.substr(2));
                    if(msg.substr(0,1)=="0"){
                        $("#txtcurpass").attr("value","");
                        $("#txtnewpass").attr("value","");
                        $("#txtcnewpass").attr("value","");
                    }
                },
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $("#chPassLoad").css("visibility","visible");
                }
            });
```

and the data that will be receive from cpf.inc.php contains html entities like this

```
&#12362;&#12399;&#12424;&#12358;&#12372;&#12374;&#12356;&#12414;&#12377;&#28450;&#23383
```

and that html entities are Japanese characters

> おはようございます漢字

now my problem is when I will receive data from the variable **msg** it returns something like this

```
pX[h&sigmaf;&#1794;
```

Is there any code I need to append on the $.ajax parameters to encode this html entities correctly? thanks

Comment: is your scripting language on server side returning you the correct characters??

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you need to set the charset for the request.. here is how you can do it:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=UTF-8');   //set the right charset here
    },
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
                url: "includes/cpf.inc.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{p_request:"1bdd249a5d673a721be31d7444af81af1af4c5b6",
                        p_userid:"<?php echo $dbu_userid; ?>",
                        p_curpass:$("#txtcurpass").val(),
                        p_newpass:$("#txtnewpass").val(),
                        p_cnewpass:$("#txtcnewpass").val()
                },
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){
                    $("#chPassLoad").css("visibility","hidden");
                    wilPrompt("#chpasStat",msg.substr(0,1),msg.substr(2));
                    if(msg.substr(0,1)=="0"){
                        $("#txtcurpass").attr("value","");
                        $("#txtnewpass").attr("value","");
                        $("#txtcnewpass").attr("value","");
                    }
                },
                beforeSend:function(xhr) {
                         xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=UTF-8');
                         $("#chPassLoad").css("visibility","visible");
                         }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem using PHP base64_encode($str) to pass XML code to jquery and decode the string with jQuery.base64. JPN fonts get problem / Chinese fonts is normal.

Use htmlentities($str,,'utf-8') instead of base64_encode is OK.